# PHP's json_encode sometimes lost its last '}' bracket when parsed by JS

Tags: javascript, php, json, fetch

I'm facing an issue when use PHP `json_encode` function. Sometimes, the encoded JSON lost `}` bracket at the end of JSON, but sometimes it's not.

The PHP code:

```
$json = json_encode([
  'type' => 'news',
  'status' => $status, // string
  'data' => $news, // array of data
], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The data contains Chinese characters. I used `fetch` on JS to request the JSON and when it parsed the JSON, it returned a `parse error` message as `unexpected end of JSON input`.

Here's what does the JSON looks like:
[image: It lost <code>}</code> at the end]

What's going wrong here???

Comment: if you hard code $status and $news are you getting proper json?

Comment: can you add `JSON_HEX_QUOT` to the options?

Comment: I did, not working.

Comment: @dhaval-chheda If I did like this:    
`$json = json_encode([
        'type' => 'news',
        'status' => $status,
        'data' => ['a' => 'asd', 'b' => 'dsa'],
 ], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

it was fine, no error.

Comment: so it looks like your $news is causing some issues

Comment: @dhaval-chheda I think the problem was on Chinese characters, there was a collision between JSON syntax and Chinese characters like dots, brackets, quotes, etc. How to handle those?

Comment: a str_replace or preg_replace

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to add a comment here. But it seems to me, encoding is not utf-8.
You can convert the encoding using [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: I did `iconv(mb_detect_encoding($json, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $json);`, still doesn't work.